# WPF Binding a int to collection

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, binding

I have the IntegerUpDown from the WPF Toolkit and like to bind this to auto generated collection (EntityCollection) from the entity-framework.

My intention: i have this UpDown-control to change the number of items in the collection.

I was able to use a converter to display the Count at the IntegerUpDown, but not to change the number of items in the collection because i had no control over the collection at ConvertBack()-function - using a IValueConverter interface.

**EDIT:**

However i cannot use a converter to solve this problem accurately. Because in ConvertBack() the collection from the model will be overrided with the modified from converter class. This is not possible in EF.
I have to use the model from the EF directly, modifying the items.

Comment: If you don't have control over the collection during ConvertBack, how do you have control during ConvertTo?

Comment: At Convert(object value, Type targetType ... i get the collection from the first parm

ICollection<WMSSim.Gasse> collection = (ICollection<WMSSim.Gasse>)value;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A collection with settable Count? That's rather unusual! Anyway, what you want to do is add a `MyCollectionCount` property to your viewmodel and bind to that:

```
public int MyCollectionCount
{
    get { return Model.MyCollection != null ? Model.MyCollection.Count : 0 ; }
    set { if    (Model.MyCollection != null)  
                 Model.MyCollection.Count = value ; /* ¬_¬ */ }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that was exactly the piece of code i needed! The count is not settable either, but i fill this with dummy instances.

Answer (score 1):

If your control is using databinding, you can pass that into the convert as a parameter:

```
<IntegerUpDown  Value="{Binding MyCollection,
                Converter={StaticResource CollectionConverter},
                ConverterParameter=MyCollection}" />
```

And use this as your converter:

```
public class UpDownConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ICollection<Type> col = (ICollection<Type>)value;

        return col.Count;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ICollection<Type> col = (ICollection<Type>)parameter;

        // Do manipulation here
    }
}
```

For more info on Converters in Xaml, [check out the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee126043.aspx).

Comment: thanks for answer, tried this before. you cannot pass a value via ConverterParameter. However i found a simple way to just save the collection at Convert-method inside the class an use this in ConvertBack but the entity-framework has some problems, too.

However i don't know how this Converters work internally. Saving this at Convert-point might not be a good idea.

Comment: I would advise against saving a reference to the collection in the converter, as you never know where the converter might be called from and you don't want to have some hanging references. But if you solved your own question, post you answer here so others can see it!

Comment: It solved the problem accessing the collection at the ConvertBack() but this leads to another problem, that i have with the EF now.
The EF don't likes overwrite the collection (via set) - instead i have to work directly on this model. Maybe my question should be more the way how to solve this not using a converter.